# output_field argument of expressionwrapper not identifying any field

Tags: django

> while using ExpressionWrapper  i am not able set
> output_field=DecimalField()  i am getting error like

1. Exception Type:  NameError
2. Exception Value: name 'DecimalField' is not defined

> > help me out with this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Value, F, ExpressionWrapper
from store.models import Customer, Product

def say_hello(request):
    discounted_price = ExpressionWrapper(
        F('unit_price') * 0.8, output_field=DecimalField())
    queryset = Product.objects.annotate(discounted_price=discounted_price)

    return render(request, 'hello.html', {'name': 'Ashish', 'result': list(queryset)})
```

Comment: You haven't imported `DecimalField` from `django.db.models`?

Answer (score 1):

from django.db.models import DecimalField

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).